# I'd like to divide several check boxes so they don't overlap and total sum, how to get "q1" and "q2" to operate separately

Tags: javascript, function

I'm a student and I'm going to make a page about the exam.

I'd like to divide several checkboxes so they don't overlap and total sum.

How can I have "q1" and "q2" operate separately?

Only one is checked per question, and whether two are sum together.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var sum=0;
        function calc(cBox) {
        var sumtext = document.getElementById("sumtext");

            if(cBox.checked)
                sum += parseInt(cBox.value);
            else
                sum -= parseInt(cBox.value);
            sumtext.value = sum;
          }


        function checkOnly(chk){

           var obj = document.getElementsByName("q1");

              for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                    if(obj[i] != chk){
                          obj[i].checked = false;
                          }
                    }
            }

          </script>


      No.1 Question<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="1"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer4
      </p>
      

      No.2 Question<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="1"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this);calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer4
      </p>

      <input type="text" id="sumtext" value="0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `checkOnly` function to add name as arg:

```
function checkOnly(chk, name){

           var obj = document.getElementsByName(name);

              for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                    if(obj[i] != chk){
                          obj[i].checked = false;
                          }
                    }
            }
```

In the HTML update the method, pass `name` as second arg:

```
 No.1 Question<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="1"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer4
      </p>
      

      No.2 Question<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="1"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this, 'q2')"  class="sum" >Answer1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="0"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer4
      </p>

      <input type="text" id="sumtext" value="0" >
```

```js
        var sum=0;
        function calc(cBox) {
        var sumtext = document.getElementById("sumtext");

            if(cBox.checked)
                sum += parseInt(cBox.value);
            else
                sum -= parseInt(cBox.value);
            sumtext.value = sum;
          }


        function checkOnly(chk, name){

           var obj = document.getElementsByName(name);

              for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                    if(obj[i] != chk){
                          obj[i].checked = false;
                          }
                    }
            }
```

```html
No.1 Question<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="1"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="2"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="3"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="4"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q1');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer4
      </p>
      

      No.2 Question<br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="1"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="2"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer2<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="3"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer3<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="q2" value="4"
      onclick="javascript:checkOnly(this, 'q2');calc(this)"  class="sum" >Answer4
      </p>

      <input type="text" id="sumtext" value="0" >
```

Comment: U were a Big help,Thanks for the tip ;p